# Kubernetes JavaClient API Pod readiness

Tags: java, kubernetes

I try to create a POD with an helm file on my Kubernetes Cluster and wait until the pod is ready.
For this I use the Kubernetes Java Client API. My code is:

```
public static String startWdPod(File specFile, String namespace, String imageName, String controllerAddress)
    throws IOException, ApiException, InterruptedException {

    LOGGER.info("Loading pod spec from {}", specFile);
    V1Pod preparedPod = (V1Pod) Yaml.load(specFile);

    // Dynamic settings
    String name = WD_NAME_BASE + UUID.randomUUID();
    Objects.requireNonNull(preparedPod.getMetadata()).setName(name);
    V1Container container = Objects.requireNonNull(preparedPod.getSpec()).getContainers().get(0);
    container.setImage(imageName);

    Objects.requireNonNull(container.getEnv()).add(new V1EnvVar().name("WD_CONTROLLER_ADDRESS").value(controllerAddress));
    LOGGER.info("Creating pod {} with image {}", name, imageName);
    V1Pod pod = getApi().createNamespacedPod(namespace, preparedPod, null, null, null);
    podReference = pod;

    int count = 0;
    LOGGER.info("POD Phase1 {}", pod.getStatus().getPhase());
    while (count < 50) {

      if (pod.getStatus().getPhase().equals("Ready")) {

        LOGGER.info("Found Ready");
        count = 50;
      }

      LOGGER.info("POD not ready, wait 1 second");
      LOGGER.info("POD Phase loop {}", pod.getStatus().getPhase());
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
      count++;
    }    

    return Objects.requireNonNull(pod.getMetadata()).getName();
  }
```

The Pod is created well and becomes ready after some time. But in my Loop the Status will never get other than "Pending". I expect it will change some time to "Ready". Is there anything I think wrong about?

Comment: From the docs: `PodStatus represents information about the status of a pod. Status may trail the actual state of a system, especially if the node that hosts the pod cannot contact the control plane.` Your while loop will likely complete all 50 iterations before the pod has had a chance to update its status.

Comment: You should not have to wait until the pod is ready. This thinking doesn't apply to kubernetes. If, for example, you want to access a db in a pod from a client, if the db isn't ready just let the client pod exit. K8s will create another client pod, repeating the process until the db is available.

Comment: @Software Engineer  .... sounds like a Linux freak. Sorry but this fire and forget thinking is oldschool. On a cluster with Windows nodes you have not the guarantee that the pod is Ready after the yaml was installed by Java Client. Some times it is possible that the Registry is slow and then your following Java code will fail. So it is a must to check when the pod becomes ready. This has nothing to do with clusters more with objects.

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand I think 50 seconds is enough. It is more that the Status get no update. 
Update: I watched with Lens and the node is in Ready state while the function stil returns "Pending".